# How to convert this table to a typical bootstrap format?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have this table that has been created, and I have applied bootstrap to the page. But I need to convert the table to a more bootstrap like table format. Here's what I have:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post your table code? Should just be a matter of adding classes. See http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more info, best advice I can give is to add .table to your table tag.

Current:

```
<table lotsofstuffhere >
```

Change to:

```
<table class="table" id="MainContent_grdSearch">
```

Comment: I couldn't copy and paste your code, you will have to interpret. Short answer is to take out all the extra stuff from your current <table> except your id and add the class "table" to it.